# Django FileResponse don't download HTML file

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to download an pre-generated HTML file, but all that i've tried doesn't work.

Searching StackOverflow i found that return `FileResponse(open(file_path, 'rb'))` will download a file, but intead of download, the HTML just is rendered on the tab. I think the problem is the browser receive the HTML and instead of display the "Save as" dialog just render it to the current tab.

In my main template i have a form with `target="_blank"` tag, and a submit button that open (**without AJAX**) a new tab who suposed to download automatically the file.

What i want: After i submit the code a new tab appears, the view related to that URL do some code (not related to the download) and after that process (that is working fine) download an HTML file to the device. The HTML exists and don't have any problem, te only problem it's that i want to DOWNLOAD the file but the browser display it instead.

Note 1: Yes, i know that with right clic -> download i can download the HTML that i see, but this system is for non IT people, i need to do it the easest way possible.
Note 2: I put the **without AJAX** message because i've found on another post that FileResponsive don't word from AJAX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put special header in your response

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cool.html"
```

```
response = FileResponse(open(file_path, 'rb'))
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="cool.html"'
return response
```